# Truncated SVD vs Partial SVD

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, pca

Can somebody tell me the difference between truncated SVD as implemented in sklearn and partial SVD as implemented in, say, fbpca?

I couldn't find a definitive answer as I haven't seen anybody use truncated SVD for principal component pursuit (PCP).

Answer (score 2):

Truncated or partial means that you only calculate a certain number of components/singular vector-value pairs (the strongest ones).

In scikit-learn parlance, "partial" usually refers to the fact that a method is on line, meaning that it can be fed with partial data. The more data you give it the better it will converge to the expected optimum.

Both can be combined, and have been, also in sklearn: `sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA` does this.

Comment: So, partial SVD is equivalent to incremental PCA in sklearn? I'm confused. If so, is that what one should use for principal component pursuit (i.e. robust PCA)?

Comment: robust pca as in low-rank + sparse from the candes paper?

Comment: Yes, the Candes paper. As I currently understand it (and correct me if I'm wrong), PCP can be used to decompose the matrix (M) into low-rank (L) and sparse (S) and is typically achieved using partial SVD? I wanted to know how to get L + S using sklearn/Python without rolling my own algorithm based on the paper. Additionally, what should I do if M is too big to fit into memory? Is there already an on-line method for determining L + S as you had mentioned? Thanks in advance

Comment: I was wrong about the nomenclature: In the literature, partial SVD is truncated SVD. It is only in sklearn parlance that partial* means using less samples.

Comment: This means that what you are probably looking for is `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds` or possibly `sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA` or even the simple `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`, where you appropriately set `n_components`

Comment: In the case of robust PCA, how does one know what n_components to set if the rank of the low-rank is not known a priori?

Comment: I don't think you can without altering the problem. You will need to allow it to have full rank and use the trace norm to reduce the rank.